# Site not showing mobile layout when accessed from my phone (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently built a website, I used bootstrap to make it responsive. Everything was working pretty smooth, when I shrank my browser it changed the layout as it was supposed to, so I thought that it was going to work the same way by the time I access it from my phone, but it turns out that I was wrong, when I access the site from my phone it displays the regular site, it doesn't render to use the mobile layout.

My code is just plain HTML and I'm using bootstrap 3, any suggestions?

Thanks in advanced.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--Seg:header-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/edison.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/edison.css" rel="stylesheet">   

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="header">
<span id="leftHeaderImg">
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.gif" /></a>
</span>
<span class="header-right-block">
<div class="header-medium-text">"One call does it all"</div>
<div class="header-phone">800-875-9626</div>
<div class="header-small-text">we handle everything for the funeral<br />
business except caskets and vaults</div>
</span>
</div>

<!--top nav menu-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<span class="navbar-brand">Menu</span>
</div><!--end of navbar-header-->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav><!--end of top nav menu-->

<!--Seg:carousel-->
<div class="col-sm-10">

<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide hidden-xs"><!-- class for animation -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
<img src="images/carrousel.png" alt="" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p>Product 1</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="images/carrousel.png" alt="" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p>Product 2</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="images/carrousel.png" alt="" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p>Product 3</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="images/carrousel.png" alt="" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<p>Product 4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- end of carousel-inner -->

<!--  Next and Previous controls -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- end of carousel -->
</div><!--end of col-sm-10 -->
<!--End:carousel-->    

<!--Seg:content-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">

<!--sidebar nav menu-->
<div class="sidebar-nav">
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Categories</span>
</div><!--end of navbar-header-->

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Acknoledgement Cards</a></li><!--class="active"-->
<li><a href="#">Air Trays</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Body Bags</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Chapel Equipment</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">Flower Handling</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">Funeral Garments</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">Jewish Service Needs</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">OSHA</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">Preparation Room</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">Rosary Beads</a></li>         
<li><a href="#">Urns</a></li>         
</ul>
</div><!--end of nav-collapse-->
</div>
</div><!--end of sidebar nav menu-->
</div><!-- end of col-sm-3 -->

<!--content-->
<div class="col-sm-9">
<div class="row">
<div class="text"><strong>Best Sellers:</strong></div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">

<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="" /></a>
<h2>Item</h2>
<p>Dummy Text! Dummy Text! Dummy Text! Dummy Text!  
Dummy Text! Dummy Text! </p>
<span class="btn btn-default">Details</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="" /></a>
<h2>Item 2</h2>
<p>Dummy Text! Dummy Text! Dummy Text! Dummy Text!  
Dummy Text! Dummy Text! </p>
<span class="btn btn-default">Details</span>
</div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end of col-xs-12-->
            </div>
        </div><!--end of col-sm-9-->
    </div> <!-- end of row-->
    <!--End:content-->



    <!--Seg:footer-->
    <footer class="row footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2014<br />
                 Site design:<a href="#"> </a><br />
                 <a href="#">Return Policy</a><br />
                 <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> 
                </p>
            </div><!--end of panel-footer-->
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--End:footer-->

<!--Seg:closePage-->
</div><!--end of container-->
<!--End:closePage-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thry this meta: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Make sure your phone's browser isn't set to desktop mode.  One thing that helps is to setup a bootply.com page that does the behavior...or make sure all your HTML CSS files are at least CDN files, etc., so that we can run them on our own computers without having to go find the links and rewrite your HTML.

Comment: seems to work fine with stock assets: http://www.bootply.com/ecehdlbPuA. Must be something in your <head>. Like @KevinNelson suggested, try using CDN styling files where possible, and if problem persists, post your custom files so we can help.